# ASP.NET vNext é interpretado que nem PHP?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

O ASP.NET vNext está apresentando bastante novidades com relação as versões anteriores, entre elas é a ideia de não compilar os códigos, basta modificar e já ver o que acontece na página. Isso significa que o ASP.NET vai ser interpretado da mesma forma que PHP é interpretado pelo Apache?

Isso me da uma preocupação, uma das vantagens que sempre vi no ASP.NET foi não expor o código fonte e não ter que mandar ele junto pro servidor na hora do deploy, basicamente só mandava os binários. Com o vNext vai ser que nem PHP que a gente manda os códigos mesmo e é tudo interpretado na hora?

Answer (score 5):

Não, ele não é interpretado, se você olhar o [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/getting-started-with-aspnet-vnext-and-visual-studio) vai ver que ele diz que o vNext usa o Roslyn para compilar o código dinamicamente, então você tem a facilidade de poder alterar o código a hora que quiser e ainda manter a performance do código compilado.

Comment: o bacana disso é que eu não preciso fazer o build da minha aplicação tudo de novo para "atualizar" parte de meu código?

Comment: tudo indica que é exatamente isso que eles querem, o que ao meu ver facilita muito a vida do programador, quantas vezes eu não atualizo o navegador só para perceber que esqueci de compilar a ultima alteração que fiz...

Comment: Ok, isso responde a parte principal da pergunta mas você poderia também responder a segunda parte dela que indaga se é necessário fazer o *deploy* fornecendo os fontes? Eu imagino que os fontes sejam necessários para conseguir a flexibilidade de editar e executar, certo? Mas se não precisar do *edit & run* e quiser fazer o *deploy* dos binários apenas, é possível?

Comment: Isso eu já não sei dizer, como é algo muito novo, eu não sei ainda como ficou a parte do deploy, se vai ter opção de pré-compilar tudo ou não.

Comment: Sim, @bigown você ainda poderá optar por fazer deploy e publicar apenas os binários, do mesmo jeito que faz atualmente.